# CKEditor setData adding P tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When i am passing HTML to a CKEditor instance, a P tag is being inserted within the HTML producing unexpected results.

For example, with the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["myEditor"].setData("<div>1</div><div>2</div>");
```

the editor does not display them as block elements (it outputs as "12" inline). Calling getData() and i see the HTML is reformatted incorrectly as:

```
"<div>
<p>
    1</div><div>2</div></p>
"
```

I've played with the enterMode configuration based on some research but haven't found a magic combination. Any suggestions? (I am using 3.6.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - we we're using regex to strip out some tags when pasting and this was also impacting initial values.